# Apply a limit to an index and cumsum'ing all values below that limit

Tags: pandas

Given a series with a numerical index that form bins, is there a simple function to sum all the bin values below the limit and place them at that limit in the series? Assume the bin values won't be evenly spaced.

Example:

```
Input
Index: Val
0.1 : 0.1
0.2 : 0.1
0.3 : 0.1
0.4 : 0.1
0.5 : 0.1

Limit = 0.3


Output

0.1 : 0
0.2 : 0
0.3 : 0.3
0.4 : 0.1
0.5 : 0.1
```

My best attempt is below, but I feel like there should be a simpler way to achieve this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser = pd.Series(data = [0.1]*10,
                index = pd.Float64Index([i/10 for i in range(1,11)]))
lim = 0.3

ser.loc[lim] = ser.loc[:lim].cumsum().iloc[-1]
ser.iloc[:np.asscalar(ser.index.get_indexer([lim]))] = 0

ser
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but why you don't just use `ser[lim] = ser[:lim].sum()` and `ser[:lim-1] = np.zeros(lim-1)`?

Comment: `lim` is not always an integer, more likely to be a float. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit simpler:

```
ser.loc[lim] = ser.loc[:lim].sum()
ser[:ser.loc[:lim].index[-2]] = 0
```

If the index is not contained, get the index with `get_loc()` with `method='nearest'` and use `iloc` for indexing:

```
lim = 0.35
ind = ser.index.get_loc(lim, method='nearest')
ser.iloc[ind] = ser.iloc[:ind+1].sum()
ser.iloc[:ind] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I achieve this for a value of lim that wasn't in the index, but I wanted to find the nearest value. I guess `ser.index.get_loc(method='nearest)` to get the nearest indexer, and swap `loc` for `iloc`?